# ASP.NET Embedded Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am just learning ASP.NET C# and have run across the following problem.

I am working with a repeater and I am struggling to get it work as "embedded". I am reading pictures from a database and I want 4 pictures per row displayed from the database. The problem is it displays the same 4 images per row instead of iterating to the next image url in the database.

Can anyone tell me how to get this working properly? I do not wish to use code-behind to solve this problem. I apologize if I did not explain this correctly, please ask me to clarify if need be. The following is my code. Thanks!

**CODE**

```
<asp:sqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceAdditional" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" ProviderName="System.Data.OleDb" 
 SelectCommand="Select ImageFileName FROM MusicArtwork WHERE music=@id" > 

 <selectparameters>
 <asp:querystringparameter name="id" type="String" querystringfield="idNum" />
 </selectparameters>
 </asp:sqlDataSource>


<asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomers" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcel">
<ItemTemplate>
<img src="art-images/works/square-thumbs/<%# Eval("ImageFileName") %>.jpg" alt="artWork" /> <!--This should be image 0--> 
<img src="location/<%# Eval("ImageFileName") %>.jpg" 
 <br/>
  <!--Next row of the next 4 new images fetched from Database-->
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomers" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceAdditional">
<ItemTemplate>
<!--put br tag on every fourth image-->
<%# Container.ItemIndex>0 && Container.ItemIndex%4==0 ? "<br/>" : "" %>

<img src="art-images/works/square-thumbs/<%# Eval("ImageFileName") %>.jpg" alt="artWork" /> 

 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```